# AllenNLP fails on "to be" sentences. Something Broke along the Way

Tags: python, allennlp

Simple sentences involving the verb, "is" return no results for semantic role labeling, either via the demo page or by using AllenNLP in Python3.8 with the latest November Bert base model.

For example, "I am here." returns nothing.

In short:

- Instances of simple "A is B" sentences don't return any results.
- I believe there should be some sort of output, as other SRL engines do return results.
- The same goes for "I am." The expected result is an ARG1 for "I" and a predicate of "am."

This used to work with an earlier version:

```
allennlp==1.0.0
allennlp-models==1.0.0
```

### Related issues or possible duplicates

- None

### Environment

OS: macOS 10.15.7 (Catalina)

Python version: 3.8.6 (via home-brew)

```
allennlp==1.2.2
allennlp-models==1.2.2
attrs==20.3.0
blis==0.4.1
boto3==1.16.24
botocore==1.19.24
catalogue==1.0.0
certifi==2020.11.8
chardet==3.0.4
click==7.1.2
conllu==4.2.1
cymem==2.0.4
dataclasses==0.6
filelock==3.0.12
ftfy==5.8
future==0.18.2
h5py==3.1.0
idna==2.10
importlib-metadata==3.1.0
iniconfig==1.1.1
jmespath==0.10.0
joblib==0.17.0
jsonnet==0.17.0
jsonpickle==1.4.1
murmurhash==1.0.4
nltk==3.5
numpy==1.19.4
overrides==3.1.0
packaging==20.4
plac==1.1.3
pluggy==0.13.1
preshed==3.0.4
protobuf==3.14.0
py==1.9.0
py-rouge==1.1
pyparsing==2.4.7
pytest==6.1.2
python-dateutil==2.8.1
regex==2020.11.13
requests==2.25.0
s3transfer==0.3.3
sacremoses==0.0.43
scikit-learn==0.23.2
scipy==1.5.4
sentencepiece==0.1.91
six==1.15.0
spacy==2.3.2
srsly==1.0.4
tensorboardX==2.1
thinc==7.4.1
threadpoolctl==2.1.0
tokenizers==0.9.3
toml==0.10.2
torch==1.7.0
tqdm==4.53.0
transformers==3.5.1
typing-extensions==3.7.4.3
urllib3==1.26.2
wasabi==0.8.0
wcwidth==0.2.5
word2number==1.1
zipp==3.4.0
```

### Steps to reproduce

[Visit the demo website for SRL](https://demo.allennlp.org/semantic-role-labeling)

**Example:**

Enter almost any variation of:
"I am here."
"We are people."
"I am."

```
#  https://demo.allennlp.org/semantic-role-labeling/MjU3NDk3NA==

# or
from allennlp.predictors.predictor import Predictor

allen_predictor_srl = Predictor.from_path(
    "./models/bert-base-srl-2020.11.19.tar.gz"
)

output = allen_predictor_srl.predict(sentence="I am here.")
print(output)

# observe nothing
```

EDIT:
I tried installing the exact library versions I used to have (i.e. AllenNLP 1.0), but the issue persists. I frankly have no idea what is going on.

EDIT 2:

Install script:

```
python3 -m venv env
source ./env/bin/activate


pip3 install --upgrade pip

pip3 install -U --no-cache-dir

pip3 install -U allennlp allennlp-models --no-cache-dir

python3 -m spacy download en_core_web_lg    --no-cache-dir
python3 -m spacy download en_core_web_sm    --no-cache-dir
python3 -m spacy download en_vectors_web_lg --no-cache-dir
python3 -m spacy download de_core_news_md   --no-cache-dir
```

Comment: It's tough being Groot

Comment: I don't understand. This is blocking a major project, and it seems to have happened out of nowhere, e.g. "This is a dog" doesn't detect any SRLs. It used to.

Comment: You may have to trace through the code of the library manually.

Comment: Different models produce different results.  I'm only seeing that on NMN Drop  --  https://demo.allennlp.org/reading-comprehension

Comment: I notice you have `cymem` listed.  It's possible there's a previous cythonized module that's being read instead of your updated scripts.  You could try deleting .pyc / .pyx from within those subdirs.

Comment: @Doyousketch2 I tried wiping the entire virtual environment I set-up and installing allennlp and allennlp-models from source. Same issue. Where is the .pyc?

I am running on macOS without any CUDA (of course since it's all Radeon discrete). Are you saying that the library works fine for you in the latest version? I figure that maybe there's something being cached too, but I'm really not sure what or where.

Comment: To clarify, is no one else experiencing this issue?

Comment: No, just saying I've run into that before, where cashed precompiled Python code was being seen instead of new script contents.  I had to delete .pyx files to get the expected results, and you had specified `--no-cache` which made me think of that.  You might have to contact them through GitHub, and submit a bug report  --  https://github.com/allenai/allennlp/issues

Comment: Yep, I've done that. No reply yet. I'm quite worried because my entire graduate product is being blocked by this. It's not only the missing "to be" results. I'm also getting poorer results in general for subordinate clauses and whatnot. Something's definitely wrong. Is there a chance someone could verify with the latest version what happens with "This is a dog?" I get: `{'verbs': [], 'words': ['This', 'is', 'a', 'dog', '.']}
`
AKA nothing.

Comment: Also, I tried downgrading to an earlier allennnlp (v 1.0, which is what I used previously) and the issue persisted.

Comment: I just confirmed that this same issue exists on a fresh install ... on a linux machine. It's all the same. Something is definitely wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To provide some closure, the issue was caused by an update in Spacy. We have a fix in https://github.com/allenai/allennlp-models/pull/178 (thank you https://github.com/wangrat), and it will be officially released in AllenNLP 1.3.

If you need this feature earlier than that, we recommend checking out the `main` branch of AllenNLP and installing it with `pip install -e .`.

Comment: Yes, I was part of that discussion. :) I’m glad it was resolved.

Comment: I'm aware, but I want to leave a useful record on Stack Overflow as well.